# Bernoulli trials question

Tags: probability

Read up on Bernolli trials, but I can't get my head around this.

> Consider a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with p = 0 2. What
>   is the expected number of trials to obtain the first success? After
>   the eighth success occurs, what is the expected number of trials to
>   obtain the ninth success?

SOS!

Comment: see [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Bernoulii trial series with success parameter $p$, the expected number of trials until the first success is: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E[N_1] & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n p (1-p)^{n-1} \\[1ex] & = \frac 1 p\end{align}$$

After eight successes have occurred the expected number of trials until the ninth success is: $$\mathsf E[N_9-N_8\mid N_8] = \mathsf E[N_1]$$

Which is to say: After *any* number of successes the expected number of trials until the *next* success remains constant; there's no memory.  This is because *after* the each success you basically start the process over again from the start.